# The response is not a valid JSON response, wordpress problems?

Tags: php

Everytime when I want to create new pages, or upload content, I have the same error.
I mention that I use ACF Wordpress - Advanced Custom Fields PRO plugin from Wordpress.

When I test on the local server, everything works fine, but on the server the changes cannot be made. What should I do ?

Comment: Please share your response headers, and the response data you are receiving. Please don't paste screenshots.